# Can the result of as operator be null if the is operator returns true?

Tags: c#, casting

I am using code quality tools and they are saying that I can have a null deference on line 3 in the following block style:

```
1    if(var1 is Type1)
2    {
3         (var1 as Type1).methodCall();
4    }
```

It sugests making the following change:

```
1    Type1 tempVar = var1 as Type1; 
2    if(tempVar != null)
3    {
4         tempVar.methodCall();
5    }
```

How does this change the potential for a null deference exception? According to msdn is will return true if "provided expression is non-null, and the provided object can be cast to the provided type without causing an exception to be thrown." (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx)

What senerio is there where `var1 is Type1` would evaluate to True, but `var1 as Type1` evaluates to null. Or is this not possible and just a limitation of the code quality tools.

I am using jetbrains re-sharper and hp fortify.

Comment: Note that second code also fixes "avoid duplicate call to `as` " warning by some tools, so you may want to just stick to it.

Comment: In addition to what servy answered below, there is also a (somewhat theoretical) performance issue. Internally, the `is` and `as` operator are doing the same thing (for reference types), so why doing it twice? (edit: like Alexei just said as well)

Comment: @KrisVandermotten That's very much a microoptimization though.  It's simply not an expensive operation.

Comment: The performance thing is a factor, a small factor. I do like the readability of it, but many times there are multiple var is type calls in a if else if ... blocks and makes it ugly.

Comment: @Servy Like I said, a somewhat theoretical performance issue. In practice it would hardly ever be detectable, not even when in a tight loop.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only way that your first program could throw a NRE is if `var1` could potentially be mutated from another thread after the check and before the method invocation.  Assuming that you don't need to be concerted about mutation from another thread (or already have proper synchronization in place)  this is a false positive of the code analysis tool and your original code won't throw a NRE.

Comment: Mandatory caveat that in multi-threaded scenarios and really bad code, tempVar could indeed be null after the check, but that's hardly very likely.

Comment: @Servy Thanks, that sounds good to me. I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something. Most of these cases are no in places where threading occurs.

Comment: +1. The other obvious possibility is `Type1 var1 {get {return count++ == 0 ? null : someValue;}` but it is probably not the case (as name implies local variable).

Answer (score 1):

The value of `var1` could change between the `is` and `as` if another thread can access it.

Even if it's unlikely, or even impossible in your specific situation, the suggested code is completely immune against such changes, so it's good practice.

The suggested code also does the type check only once, so it even performs slightly better. Even if the performance difference is not always significant, it still means that you get better code at no extra cost.